# Как узнать имя хоста докера?

Tags: docker

Я использую докер для того, чтоб работать с двумя mysql(5.5, 5.7). Хочу подключить базу к IDE, но не знаю какой хостнейм использовать. Если просматриваю порты занятые и хосты, то выводит

> tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*
>   LISTEN      14740/docker-proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробрось порты на localhost.

```
 # docker-compose.yml

 ports:
   - 3306:3306
```

Или `docker run -p 3306:3306`

Левый port на localhost. В другом контейнере делай `3307` или любой другой не занятый. Используй `localhost:3306` или `3307` (etc).